# How to specify the location where entry_points scripts are installed in python package?

Tags: python, package, debian, setup.py

I have a python package with setup.py file like so:

```
 setup(name=project_name,
    packages=find_packages(exclude=['ez_setup', 'examples', 'tests']),
    include_package_data=True,
    zip_safe=False,
    entry_points="""
    [console_scripts]
    sound-run = sound.run:start
    sound-resume = sound.run:resume
    """
    # Other setuptools stuff
    )
```

I am trying to make it such that when installed as a debian package, the scripts (sound-run, sound-resume) binaries end up in a destination I specify. Currently when I make the debian package the scripts end up in /usr/local/bin/ but I would like to have them install into /usr/local/myfolder/myfolder1.

Any suggestions?

Comment: setup.py is just python script, which is run. You shall be able to precalculate values of the setup parameters at the moment it installs. But I am not sure if console_scripts allows doing this - simply do not know and did not research it.

Answer (score 0):

`python setup.py --install-scripts destination`.  See the `--help` option and https://docs.python.org/2.7/install/index.html#custom-installation

Note that this is provided by distutils, which setuptools extends; I assume that setuptools entry-points-generated scripts also respect that option.

Regarding your use case, Debian has specific helpers that will install things to the right locations so that the Debian tools can finish the job.  I’d advise to look into using dh with pybuild and dh_python2.